# How to make DataGridView editing control entry behaviour the same as TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to make entering a DataGridView textbox cell work exactly like entering a TextBox? By default, text can be selected in a TextBox just by clicking and dragging the mouse, even when the control doesn't start with the focus, but in a DGV you seem to have to select the cell before you can vary the selected text.

EDIT: I am trying to make the DataGridView behave the same as tables in MS Access where you can dynamically select text in a cell which doesn't already have the focus with a *single* click and drag. (I notice that in Access the text shows as selected before the cell receives focus, so is not quite the same as I am asking above, but would also be acceptable.)

Once the cell editing control has focus, text selection works fine, but I can't seem to make it happen when entering the cell in the first place.

I am currently using programmatical editing using `DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)` to show the editing control, but the only options here are `False` (nothing selected) or `True` (all text selected). *Edit:* Using `EditOnEnter` causes the whole cell text to be selected and another mouse click is needed to dynamically select just a portion of the cell contents.

Surely behaviour like this ought to be possible since `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` inherits `TextBox` anyway?

Comment: `EditMode = EditOnEnter`

Comment: This is not a question you should need to ask. If you want to something with a specific control, e.g. a `DataGridView`, the very first thing you should do is read the documentation for that control. VS has a Help menu for a reason. That documentation will, among other things, provide a list of all members (properties, methods, events) of that type and a description of each, as well as a link to further information. If you'd done that then you'd have found for yourself that `EditMode` property. By reading the documentation, you may also find other useful information you weren't looking for

Comment: @jmcilhinney: please make sure you understand the question before being disparaging. Unless I am mistaken, `EditOnEnter` selects the whole text when the cell is clicked which is not the same as a TextBox where you can enter the control and dynamically select text in a single click.

Comment: You mistake criticism for disparagement. Don't be so sensitive. You should have read the documentation and found that property. If the subsequent behaviour was not exactly what you wanted then you could have asked a question clearly and specifically about that behaviour. Don't assume that we will infer meaning not clearly indicated.

Comment: While editing a cell in a dgv an actual, genuine TextBox is overlaid, so there should not be any difference. But yes, you need to start editing. Various was to make that happen automatically; Lars told you one..

Comment: @TaW I don't know about the TextBox one, but even though the DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl inherits ComboBox, they have changed it so it doesn't behave like a standard ComboBox (in terms of list selection and item values). It is possible (likely?) that they've changed the behaviour of the DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl too. As regards 'starting editing' see my edits to the original post.

Comment: Well a DGV is closer to excel than access and in excel you also need to enter edit mode before you can select. Yes, this is different from single textboxes because in a DGV there are many cells and selecting one or more is a normal action. Not sure how to workaround nor if that is even a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're asking is possible, here is something very close.

```
    private void OnCellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs cellMouseEventArgs)
    {
        if (cellMouseEventArgs.RowIndex < 0 || cellMouseEventArgs.ColumnIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var cellRef = _dataGridView[cellMouseEventArgs.ColumnIndex, cellMouseEventArgs.RowIndex];
        if (cellRef == null || cellRef.IsInEditMode || cellRef.ReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }
        _dataGridView.BeginEdit(false);
        if (!(cellRef is DataGridViewComboBoxCell))
        {
            return;
        }
        var editingControl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (editingControl != null)
        {
            editingControl.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

And subscribe like normal of course `_dataGridView.CellMouseClick += OnCellMouseClick;`

The behaviour this produces is such that when you click editing starts, this also has an improvement for combo boxes which usually take 2 or 3 clicks to open, this does it in one. You cannot select text immediately, you must click once still. I have experimented with MouseEnter and similar and cannot produce exactly what you are asking for unfortunately. if anyone else has a complete solution please do submit it because I would also like it!